# undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Why is my code returning this error?

```
@articles = Article.order("id DESC").where(:visible => 1)
if @aritcles.size > 15
  @articles = Article.order("id DESC").where(:visible => 1).limit(15)
end
```

returns:

```
undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

If i run

```
@articles = Article.order("id DESC").where(:visible => 1)
@articles.size
```

It returns an integer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is from your real code, then you mispelled `articles` to `aritcles`.

If that is different, please provide the real code.

Comment: Haha Whoops! My bad. Coding at 2am can do that to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`if @aritcles.size > 15` should be `if @articles.size > 15`.

But your code is odd, it is not necessary to do that.
Just do the below is enough.

```
@articles = Article.order("id DESC").where(:visible => 1).limit(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`@aritcles.size > 15`
By
 `@articles.seze > 15`